# .NETCore - JSON Web Tokens With Multiple Validation Rules

Tags: asp.net-core

In .NETCore asp net I am using UseJwtBearerAuthentication to protect controllers using access tokens in a manner similar to this:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions  
{
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = "TestIssuer",

        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = "TestAudience",

        ValidateLifetime = true,
    }
});
```

However, I want to provide more than one set of options as there is the potential that different audiences will require different levels of access. For instance, access tokens may need to have different lifetimes.

I can achieve this by adding the different options like this:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(jwtBearerOptions1);  
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(jwtBearerOptions2);
```

This works fine. And access is granted to the controllers as expected.

However, the problem I've found is that while I'm correctly granted or denied access as expected, the debug console receives a lot of verbose exception messages as the .NET authentication code tries to authenticate against each of the available JwtBearerOptions.

It will record that one has been successful but also every one that has failed (example below).

My question: Is there a way to suppress this message as I expect there to be these failures? Or should I use a different method to allow multiple JwtBearerOptions to be added?

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidSignatureException: IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey , KeyId: 
'.
Exceptions caught:
 ''.
token: '{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"}.{"sub":"testuser","jti":"c98bb91a-5dcd-4fd7-97ff-c10cddf18989","nbf":1497015309,"exp":1497101709,"iss":"TestIssuer","aud":"TestAudience"}'.
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.<HandleAuthenticateAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerMiddleware[7]
      Bearer was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey , KeyId: 
      '.
```

Comment: The link below is to the code that results in this error message. It looks like there is no way to stop this. https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/82c231efca8a4afdc471929020a42038b90ba78e/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/JwtBearerHandler.cs#L93